# Download specific version of a file from SharePoint using web services

Tags: web-services, sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

Can someone provide a sample for downloading a specific version of a file from SharePoint using web services? Normally I would get the file with the Copy Web Service (.../_vti_bin/copy.asmx). But I don't really know how to specify a version.

Regards

Anton Kalcik

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [Versions web service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/da-dk/library/versions.versions.getversions(en-us).aspx) to get which versions exist for a File

The GetVersions method will give you an xml like this:

```
<results xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/">
   <list id="{26E516B0-8241-4B97-984D-000000000000}" />
      <versioning enabled="1" />
   <settings url="http://Server_Name/Site_Name/_layouts/
         1033/LstSetng.aspx?
      List={26E516B0-8241-4B97-984D-000000000000}" />
   <result version="@4" url="http://Server_Name/Site_Name/
         Shared Documents/File_Name.doc" 
      created="6/7/2003 5:55 PM" createdBy="DOMAIN\User" size="19968" 
         comments="" />
   <result version="1" url="http://Server_Name/Site_Name/
         _vti_history/1/Shared Documents/File_Name.doc" 
      created="6/7/2003 5:49 PM" createdBy="DOMAIN\User" size="19968" 
         comments="" />
      .
      .
      .
</results>
```

You can then just use a HTTP GET request for the content of the "url" attribute of the "result" node for the right version

Answer (score 0):

Here's the exact thing you want to do, with code:

[Article](http://ubercode.bleakllc.com/2009/03/how-to-download-any-version-of-document.html)